# Raising event after Parallel.For completes job

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, events

After pressing button following function is called.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{ 
    Parallel.For(0, cyclesCount, i => DoWork(i));

    if (OnJobCompleted != null)
        OnJobCompleted(this, EventArgs.Empty);                
});
```

Further in code there is

```
void ladder_OnJobCompleted(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    txbDebug.Text = "completed";
}
```

I know

```
txbDebug.Text = "completed";
```

has to be Invoked, beacause I'm raising event on different thread. But I can't figure out, how to Invoke it. This **event is situated in wpf form**.

Comment: Have you tried `txbDebug.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { txbDebug.Text = "completed"; }));`?

Comment: Ah, Dispatcher. It's my first project in WPF, I didn't know about Dispatcher property. Thank you. Please post your answer as regular answer in order to allow me vote you up ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Dispatcher`

```
txbDebug.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    txbDebug.Text = "completed";
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not expect you to want to use the new [Async CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=9983), but if you are curious how this would be done with the new `async` and `await` keywords proposed for C# 5 then consider the following example. It really does not get any more elegant than this.

```
void async YourButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
  txbDebug.Text = await Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(
    () =>
    {
      Parallel.For(0, cyclesCount, i => DoWork(i));
      return "complete";
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for example, I don't want use that package neither my customers. But I like it, I'm really looking forward to realasing C# 5.